# Can I create a static electricity water magnet?

Tags: electrostatics, magnetic-fields

I came to watch a video that water dipole get attracted by static electricity. I wanted to know if I could make a static electricity device that could pull out all the water from a wet cloth.

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't work. First, to get enough force so that the static attraction would overcome the capillary force of the cloth, you'd need to have a very large potential difference and be very close to the cloth. Second, water in the real world is almost always conductive; as soon as any of the water touched your highly charged attractor, the charge would be discharged and the attraction lost.

Comment: Can water vapour be attracted by electrostatic force?

Comment: No; although $H_2O$ is polarized, it has no net charge. A field could spin the molecule (e.g. microwave ovens), but wouldn't attract it.

Comment: What would be effect when electrostatic force is made in a water vapour filled area. Like a balloon electrostatically charged is placed in water vapour filled area.

Comment: Water vapor consists of individual water molecules dispersed in air. Are you instead thinking of fog, which consists of tiny water drops, each with many molecules of water? Yes, those could be charged and pushed/pulled by an electrostatic field. But what does this have to do with this question?

Comment: Just clarifying my doubts. Thank you a lot sir. One more question, Does rain clouds get attracted by static electricity.?

Comment: Just clarifying my doubts. Thank you a lot sir. One more question, Does rain clouds get attracted by static electricity.?

Comment: Rain clouds certainly interact with static electricity (e.g. lightning). I doubt, though, that you could attract any bulk cloud with a charge, as the cloud would have to be bulk charged and that would disperse it.

Comment: If you want water from a cloth, maybe microwave it?

Comment: @DanielGriscom indeed, the fact that lightning happens, and moves massive amounts of charge, and doesn't send clouds rocketing across the sky, probably says something about this whole idea :)